# Switch between apps

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I have a scenario which I need to switch Apps by using Selenium and Appium.
I'm starting with the browser, then I need to have some information from notification bar and then switch back to the browser. 
I managed to do each process as a stand-alone. but now I'm struggling doing it as End to End process.

I have started by creating a webdriver session, but I can't open a new session while he first one is still running. the problem is that the browser and appium have different sessions. One is being called by

```
_driver = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

And the second one by

```
_webdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

Comment: If you want to use two drivers at the same `Uri` and `port`. One way to do that would be : 

    `_driver = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
    // Perform the action with the browser here
    _driver.quit();
    
    _webdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
    //Perform the action with the notification bar here
    _webdriver.quit();`

Comment: @guy 
your solution might be problematic since I need to scroll the notification bar during the browser session , or at least get back to the browser just after getting the info I need from the notification bar.

Comment: @YanivEliav I didn't give you any solution, just edited the question.

Comment: sorry,
I meant @nullpointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do what needed.
All I needed to do is to run AndroidDriver first with Chrome appActivity and appPackage.

Then, use `driver.Context = NATIVE_APP;` in order to use the Android's activities.
going back to chrome is pretty easy as well. `driver.context = "WEBPAGE_1";`
this syntax belongs to C#.

in order to know which context you are currently using, use this code:

```
var Handledcontext=driver.Context.Tostring();
```

good luck and thank you all for trying helping me.

Answer (score 0):

First you execute your test in browser using remote webdriver by setting the command time out to large value..then save the sessionid in a file..then close the process without quitting the browser..
Second you execute your test using appium driver..and quit it
Again reconnect your first session with the sessionid that you saved in the file..

If you use node client then it is very easy
To get sessionid: driver.getSessionId();
To attach to existing session: driver.attach('your session id', function(err, capability){
});

If you are using any other client language like java or c# 
Then you have to override execute method of selenium to attach to existing session

Comment: unfortunately none of the solutions suggested worked. frustrating.